# Why doesn't the insert function work in this simple hash table implementation?

Tags: c, hashtable

I have tried inserting the value in the hashTable but everything after the insert function doesnt execute so I cant really figure out if the insert function is even working or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //for strcpy and strcmp

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 20 //max length of a string
#define ARRAY_SIZE 11  

typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element{
    char* names;
    int freq;
};

Element* hashTable[ARRAY_SIZE];

int hash_function(char* s){
    int hash = 0;
    while(*s){
        hash = (hash + *s)%ARRAY_SIZE;
        s++;
    }
    return hash;
}

Element* createNewElement(char* name){
    Element* item;
    strcpy(item->names,name);
    item->freq=1;
    return item;
}

void insert(char* name){
   Element* b=createNewElement(name);
   int index=hash_function(name);
   
   while(hashTable[index]!=NULL)                            //the name is inserted in the hash table using linear probing technique
    {
       index=(index+1)%ARRAY_SIZE;
    }                                                       //the name is added at the first empty spot and then loops back to the start if the hash table size is exceeded
    hashTable[index]=b;
}

void print()
{int i;
    for(i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(hashTable[i]!=NULL)
        printf("%d: %s\n",i,&hashTable[i]->names);
        else
        printf("%d: -----\n",i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    insert("jacob");
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried everything but the code after the insert refuses to work. I really need help on this one

Comment: `Element* item; strcpy(item->names,name);` `item` is an unintialised pointer. You can't validly access it in that state. `malloc` some memory. Ensure you do the same for the `char* names;` field - either define that as a static array or will need to dynamically allocate memory for that too.

Comment: Also, on line 48, this `&hashTable[i]->names` should be `hashTable[i]->names`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Element* createNewElement(char* name){
>     Element* item;
>     strcpy(item->names,name);
>     item->freq=1;
>     return item;
> }
> ```

`item` and `item->names` are uninitialized pointers. `createNewElement` needs to allocate memory for the `Element` and then for the name.

```
Element* createNewElement(char* name){
    Element* item = malloc(sizeof *item);
    if (!item) {
        // handle allocation failure
    }
    item->names = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    if (!item->names) {
        free(item);
        // handle allocation failure
    }
    strcpy(item->names,name);
    item->freq=1;
    return item;
}
```